# should i use @font-face or an image for a complicated fancy heading

Tags: html, css, font-face

I've got a web page that has a fancy heading.  I have the option of using @font-face to render it or make it an image. the font is only used in this one heading

i've found the @font-face option a bit tricky to implement well across browsers as the heading is quite complicated in terms of size and alignments.  also the font itself doesnt render itself exactly the same between browsers.

So i was thinking of just using the image option with alt tag.  are there any real issues with doing this? SEO considerations?

Answer (score 1):

In short, its up to you.  For something cosmetic like this, I'd do both fonts and background images.  Make it work in modern browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari, IE9(?) ), then add fallbacks with images for IE6, and other browsers not up to snuff.

Using an image (i.e. `<img />` tag) is probably your worst bet.  Headers tags hold their weight in water when it comes to SEO junk, so the more meaningful markup you have, the better.

> also the font itself doesnt render itself exactly the same between browsers.

[Read here...](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing **wrong** with using an image as a header, as long as you do it right (putting them in the appropriate header tags, etc). Using an `alt` tag is sometimes not enough. I'd suggest looking into some image-replacement techniques.  Here's a extensive (and pretty good) list:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageReplacement/